# Timepicker for selecting Hours,mins, and secs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a good **Timepicker**.
Where i can select hours minutes and secs.
I found this [jQuery](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) but none of the examples show way to select hours minutes and secs.

Thanks :)

Comment: [**Bootstrap timepicker**](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)

Comment: @shaunakde Can I have another option please because, I don't want to get bootstrap timepicker as it requires bootstrap.css which modifies my other custom css if I import it my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Timepickers :

1. [Timepicker 1](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)
2. [Timepicker 2](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)
3. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/
4. http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

Any+Time(TM) version 3.x which uses jQuery instead of Prototype and has a much-improved interface, so I hope it now meets your needs:
http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Just to add to the info here, The Fluid Project has a nice wiki write-up overviewing a large number of date and/or time pickers [here](http://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/Infusion13/Date+Time+Picker+Competitive+Analysis).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

[LINK](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tengcalendar.shtml)

Its a simple one

Answer (score 0):

Dojo-dijit has something similar to jQuery (dropdown of intervals) - dijit/form/TimeTextBox

But Dojo-mobile has a better one, which can select hours and mins separately and is compact. You should be able to add seconds also - dojox/mobile/TimePicker

Sample/Demo:
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_TimePicker.html
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/mobile/tests/test_ValuePickerTimePicker.html